# Visual Studio 2013 + IE11 debug hangs at startup

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, internet-explorer-11, freeze

I have a fairly strong laptop (i7 quad core, 16gb, ssd+hdd), and when running an ASP.NET project in IE11 so that I can debug in VS, at the startup of the page I have to wait around 6-8 secs before I can click on anything. It's a very JS heavy project, but when I open the same thing from IIS, it's instantaneous, and it also is on my college's laptop which is lower specced (core2, 4gb, hybrid sshd). I tried to google it with no luck.

edit1:

IE11 doesn't hang, just the page inside, and also sometimes it takes as long that it says the script is running for too long.
I understand that debugging can slow down execution, but on a lower specced laptop it's fine, that's why I'm puzzled (and annoyed).

edit2:

I've tried reinstalling, and it helped a bit but still not instantaneous as for my college

edit3:

**I have reinstalled my laptop and it works fine now, sorry but I can't try any solution from now on**

Comment: 6-8 seconds? Sometimes I can go to smoke and when I return back it is still loading. Do not get mad with this :P

Comment: if you just debug the project maybe disable the compilation on each execution in configuration manager the check "Build"

Comment: The project is already built, IE has loaded, I already see the loading screen, and it's even gone (I do it when my scripts are done) and afterwards the page hangs inside IE11.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try delete .suo file and all breakpoints?

Answer (score 0):

If you CTRL-F5 from VS to run without debugging, does it run at the expected speed? This would indicate if it's the debugging explicitly which is slowing it down (rather than the local web server or the script running on the page at launch).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback (un)fortunately I can't try it, since I had it with it and I reinstalled the laptop and now it works fine.